# Understanding a regular expression \?[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}!

Tags: python, regex

I am little confused with following regular expression in python.I understand [A-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2} part of it,but could not understand what /? and trailing ! mean.

```
\?[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}!
```

Can someone give me valid examples.Also ,does the regular expression interpretation vary according to language?(java,python etc)

Comment: The `\?` simply matches a question mark - it needs to be escaped with the backslash because otherwise it has special meaning in the regex syntax. The `!` is just an exclamation mark. It doesn't have any special meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\? matches a question mark
[A-Z]{2} matches two capital letters following question mark
[a-z]{2} matches two small letters following the above pattern
[0-9]{2} matches two digits following above pattern
! matches an exclamation mark following above pattern
```

So: \?[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}! tested against:

```
?AZay06!
?AZay0pp
?AZay97pp!
```

First of the above strings will match.

I learnt regex at http://www.regexone.com/ . In my experience, interpretations of regular expressions do not vary, but the procedure to use them with delimiters does change sometimes language to language.

Answer (score 0):

The `\?` is a literal question mark. The backslash escapes the metacharacter, making it a literal. The `!` is a literal exclamation point.

Different engines support different features, but all of them support a minimum set.